# Rails set the value of a field based on another field in the same record via Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called Contacts.  Two of it's columns are called email and maxname.   When the Contact is created, I would to set maxname the the text before the @ in the email field.  So, if a new Contact is jebb@gmail.com, then his maxname should be jebb.

Just for testing I'm trying to put the whole email into maxname (before I figure out how to parse the email text).

So, in the Contacts Model I put this code:

```
  before_create :set_maxname
  before_update :set_maxname

  protected
  def set_maxname
    self.maxname = self.email
  end
```

That works.  But, how can I parse the self.email so I just get the part before the @   ??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It the record saved at all?

Comment: Wait - it did work.  I had a typo

Comment: Any idea how I could parse the self.email so I just get the part before the @   ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, doing `self.email.split('@')[0]` would work.

Edit: Also, the self isn't really necessary in this example. It's explicit, but not required.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use,

```
self.email.gsub(/@.*/,'')
```